# Geopandas installation error distutils.errors.CompileError

Tags: python, geopandas

I have been using `pip install geopandas` for installing the library on my Mac (OS: Mojave v10.14). However, I have been unsuccessful to install so far.

Here is the error I get:

```
Collecting pyproj (from geopandas)
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/8c/1da0580f334718e04f8bbf74f0515a7fb8185ff96b2560ce080c11aa145b/pyproj-1.9.6.tar.gz (2.8MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.8MB 9.0MB/s 
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
using bundled proj4..
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/pip-install-C35peF/pyproj/setup.py", line 86, in <module>
    objects = cc.compile(['nad2bin.c', 'src/pj_malloc.c'])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
    self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 125, in _compile
    raise CompileError, msg
distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-C35peF/pyproj/
```

Any ideas why this might be happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Pyproj PyPI is outdated. You can either install GeoPandas via Conda or follow steps described in this GH issue https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/793 and install pyproj beforehand from Github via

```
pip install git+https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj.git#egg=pyproj
```

and then go for `pip install geopandas`.